# How correctly add javascript on page dynamically so that it could catch on-page-load event?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, onload

I have a JS code which dynamically fetches from server the HTML which can contain JS code sometimes. If this HTML contains JS code, this JS code never handles onLoad event and as a result executes not properly. What is the correct way to add JS code on page dynamically so that it could catch onLoad event?

Comment: you could manually trigger the "domcontentloaded" event on the dynamic HTML after appending it to the browser

Answer (score 0):

Main JavaScript:

```
document.body.appendChild(dynamicHTML);
dynamicHTML.dispatchEvent(new Event('DOMContentLoaded'))
```

Dynamic HTML:

```
<div>some html</div>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  // your normal JS code
}, false);
```

Comment: you could also just use a custom Event, just to make sure that something else doesnt trigger this unintentionally